# Trigonometric ratios problem

Tags: trigonometry

[image]
How can we find $x$ in this question without knowing $sin$, $cos$, $tan$, $cot$, $sec$ or $csc$ of given angles

Comment: I can't: I know $\tan 15°$.

Comment: does the question specifically ask to find $x$ without trig ratios or you just don't know any trig ratios for $15^\circ$?

Comment: Is this a right triangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x\cos15°\sin15°=\text{BA}\sin15°=3$$ so that $$x=\frac6{\sin30°}=12.$$

(Assuming that you are allowed to "know" the value of $\sin30°$. Otherwise observe in the figure that $\text{AB}=\text{OA}=2\text{AN}$.)

[image]

Comment: How did you find out that $xcos15°sin15°$=$BAsin15°$?

Comment: Actually I found out $x\cos15°=\text{BA}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$\begin{align}\frac{AH}{AB}&=\sin(15^{\circ})\\
\frac{AB}{BC}&=\cos(15^{\circ})
\end{align}$$
(why?) we have
$$\frac{3}{x}=\frac{AH}{BC}=\sin(15^{\circ})\cos(15^{\circ})\text{.}$$
You really need to know *something* about $\sin(15^{\circ})\cos(15^{\circ})$—or perhaps $2\,\sin(15^{\circ})\cos(15^{\circ})$?—to proceed from here.

Comment: I do but we need to find it using a calculator suppose that I don't have any calcularltor how can I solve this

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Extend $\overrightarrow{HA}$ to point $D$ such that $m\angle DBA = 15^\circ$

Let $HD = x$. Since $\triangle BDH$ is a $30-60-90$ right triangle, then $AD = x-3$, $BD = 2x$, $BX = \sqrt 3 x$

By the angle bisector theorem,

\begin{align}
   \dfrac{2x}{x-3} &= \dfrac{\sqrt 3x}{3} \\
  \dfrac{x-3}{3} &= \dfrac{2}{\sqrt 3} \\
  x-3 &= 2 \sqrt 3 \\
  x &= 3+2\sqrt 3 \\
\hline
   AH &= 3 \\
   AD &= 2\sqrt 3 \\
   BD &= 6+4\sqrt 3 \\
   BH &= 6 + 3\sqrt 3 \\
   BA &= 6\sqrt{2+\sqrt 3}
\end{align}

Since $\triangle ACH \cong \triangle BAH$, then 
\begin{align}
   \dfrac{AH}{CH} &= \dfrac{BH}{AH} \\
   AH^2 &= BH \cdot CH \\
   9 &= (6+3\sqrt 3)CH \\
   CH &= \dfrac{3}{2+\sqrt 3} \\
   CH &= 6-3\sqrt 3 \\
\hline
   BC &= 12
\end{align}

Comment: Why do you make it so complicated ?

Comment: I did it without using any trigonometry.

Comment: How is $AD$ equalt to $x-\sqrt 3$ ? Where is $X$ ? And how do you know that $BD=2x$ without trigonometry ?

Comment: AD is x-3 because HD is x and HA is 3. Triangle BHD is a 30-60-90 triangle. You don't need trig to know that the sides are $1:2:\sqrt 3$.

Comment: Trigonometry (from Greek trigōnon, "triangle" and metron, "measure") is a branch of mathematics that studies relationships involving lengths and angles of triangles.

Comment: Care to fix the typos, maybe.

Comment: Correct what typos?

Comment: Haha, you silently fixed one, but there's one left. Congrats!

Answer (score 1):

We know that in a triangle with angles $30,60,90$ degrees, the opposed side to $30$ is half of hypotenuse. This statement no needs trigonometry.

Now using this, try to prove that in the given triangle " the altitude is $1/4$ of hypotenuse" by drawing the median $AM$.

Comment: "This statement no needs trigonometry": this statement is nothing else than $\sin\theta=\frac12$.

Comment: Yes, but we prove this for students in which no passed any trigonometry course